# How would you implement a thread-safe function which reads from a shared hashtable using a key and updates the value in a multi-threaded environment?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, hashtable, mutex

Suppose we have some function which takes in a key, retreives its value from a shared hashtable, and perform some operations on it to obtain a new value , and then updates the hashtable with this new value. Now, this function is multi-threaded so there could be multiple threads calling this same function, either with the same or different keys, so some sort of race condition protection using mutex is necessary. I've come up with the following implementation in python using locks, where I use a dict as a hashtable. (I know that in python, dict operations are atomic but this is just for illustration purposes for the sake of the algorithm)

```
class Solution:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.datamap = {}
        self.lockmap = {}
        self.datamap_lock = Lock()
        self.lockmap_lock = Lock()

    def initializeKey(self, key):
        with self.datamap_lock:
            if key not in self.datamap:
                self.datamap[key] = (-sys.maxsize, 0)
                with self.lockmap_lock:
                    self.lockmap[key] = Lock()

    def getLock(self, key):
        with self.lockmap_lock:
            return self.lockmap[key]

    def getValue(self, key):
        with self.datamap_lock:
            return self.datamap[key]

    def storeValue(self, key, max_, value):
        with self.datamap_lock:
            self.datamap[key] = (max_, value)

    def calc(self, key, param_value):
        self.initializeKey(key)
        with self.getLock(key):
            max_, value = self.getValue(key)
            # Does some operations on value to obtain a new value
            self.storeValue(key, max_, value)
```

Basically I used a mutex for the hashtable, a mutex for each key and a mutex for the hashtable which maps from the key to the mutex. Would this implementation be correct and thread-safe? Is there a way to do it better without using so many locks/mutexes?

Comment: I think there are some flaws n your code: places where a race condition could take place. 
But I guess it could be done with a single lock equivalent to your "datamap_lock": use it to protect both "data_map" and "lock_map"  access - yu gain nothing by separating access there -  and a lock-pool, with the aproximate size of the number or threads (instead of one lock per key): one lock would be used from the pool in the lockmap only when updating one value, and returned to the pool afterwards. Sorry, I am not in a setting I can write this as a proper answer now.

Comment: My initial intention to split into 2 locks is so that when the lock for one of the maps(E.g. datamap) gets acquired, it does not block other threads from accessing the other map(E.g. lockmap), which could have some performance impact.

Answer (score 3):

It can be a lot simpler than what you are trying there:
A single lock can control the `lock_map` access, and any value in there, even a boolean, can work as a "soft lock" from that point on:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from time import sleep, monotonic
from threading import RLock

TIMESTEP = 0.0001 # 1/10th of ms between locking retries: should be a nice magnitude
# Factor out all locking logic to a single function:

class Solution:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.datamap = {}
        self.lockmap = {}
        self.lock = RLock()
        
    @contextmanager
    def get_lock(self, key, timeout=None):
        # No other method should touch "self.lockmap"
        
        retry = True
        
        start = monotonic()
        try:
            while retry:
                retry = False
                with self.lock: # use the local lock to modify the lockmap
                    if not self.lockmap.get(key, False):
                        self.lockmap[key] = True
                    else:
                        retry = True
                        time.sleep(TIMESTEP)
                        if timeout is not None:
                            if monotonic() - start > timeout:
                                raise TimeoutError()
            yield 
        finally:
            with self.lock:
                try:
                    del self.lockmap[ley]
                except KeyError:
                    pass 
        

    def initializeKey(self, key):
        with self.get_lock(key):
            if key not in self.datamap:
                self.datamap[key] = (-sys.maxsize, 0)
    def getValue(self, key):
        # with self.get_lock(key):   # this is not needed in Python - read-only from the datamap dict is atomic
            return self.datamap[key]

    def storeValue(self, key, max_, value):
        with self.get_lock(key):  # This will prevent a value from bein written while a "calc" is being performed
            self.datamap[key] = (max_, value)

    def calc(self, key, param_value):
        self.initializeKey(key)
        with self.get_lock(key):
            max_, value = self.getValue(key)
            # Does some operations on value to obtain a new value
            
            # with the  "soft_lock" mechanism in get_lock, writtings to datamapa[key] are
            # protected, and other threads are free to access and mutate other keys!
            ...
            
            # not really needed call a method to store the value. If you do this, "get_lock" would have
            # to implement the logic of a re-entrant lock (threading.RLock() ) 
            ## self.storeValue(key, max_, value)
            # if you modify datamap directly here, it is protected by our "soft_lock"
            self.datamap[key] = (max_, value)
```

Just clarifying the role of the  `yield` statement in `get_lock`: the @contextmanager decorator makes it so that this method pauses at this point, and the `with` block in the user code is executed. Execution resumes after the `with`  block on the next line after the `yield`, if everything went ok, or inside the "finally" regardless of an exception that might have taken place on the target code.

Answer (score 1):

```
    def calc(self, key, param_value):
        self.datamap_lock.acquire()
```

No, please don't do that.

Prefer to use a
[context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#with-locks):

```
        with self.datamap_lock:
            ...
```

Then you won't neglect to release the lock.
Even if an unexpected exception happens.

Oh, wait, I see you may release part way through.
Please don't do that,
as it makes it harder to reason about the code's behavior.
It's a bit like preferring structured `while` loops
over spaghetti `goto`.

I guess it's "fine" that you double acquire a reentrant Lock.
But it's unclear why that's desirable.
Stick to `with` blocks.

```
        # Does some operations on value to obtain a new value and put it back into the hash table
```

Ok, good.

But it's not obvious what lock(s) we hold at this point.
Break out that code fragment as a helper,
and make it clear that a certain lock is held
for exactly the duration of that helper's execution.

---

Your central difficulty seems to be enforcing this invariant:

Whenever a `[key]` entry is visible to other threads,
a corresponding `Lock` object shall also exist and shall be unlocked.

Recommend you
[allocate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)
that responsibility to the "add a key to the dict" code,
rather than putting it in `calc()`.
Then it becomes a simple matter to grab that (already existing) Lock
whenever we perform a calculation on some `key`.

Comment: Thanks I've edited my code based on your inputs